# Java TCP client-server connection using Public IP

Tags: java, tcp, ping

The server looks like this(Simplified)

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
PrintWrite out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
out.println("42");
```

The client looks like this(Simplified)

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("My public IP",port);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String data;
while(true){
    if((data = in.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(data);
        break;
    }
}
```

Additional settings/actions:

- Open firewall on servermachine for incoming traffic on the port in question.
- Forwarding port in router to private IP of servermachine(192.168.x.x).
- Get the public IP to the server by searching for it on www.whatismyip.com

This Question became an answer and now describes the setup for sending the answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything through cyberspace.

Comment: it could be possible with many of the reason, but without code cannot say anything . Where actually you are facing the issue and at which line and what is the error message, please update above.

Comment: Define 'can't connect'.

Comment: The Client dont get through to the serversocket, can't make connection.

Comment: Sigh. Define 'can't connect', 'don't get through', 'can't make connection', 'is never initialized', and every other paraphrase of the actual error message you may have planned to irrelevantly and uselessly serve up here instead of actually answering the question properly.

Comment: I've used WireShark to check the network communication and when I try to initialize the clientSocket a packet is sent to the public IP and port in question. But there is no response. So after a few retransmissions the client stops sending packets. This is what I meant with  'can't connect', 'don't get through', 'can't make connection', 'is never initialized'. I understand that my question might be fussy in many ways. And the comment I made above makes no sense at all, I see that now. Hope this comment makes more sense. If not please give more feedback on how I can improve my question.

Comment: Test it in LAN. If it works, it's a network setup problem. If it doesn't, come back again.

Comment: It now works using public IP. I've stumbled with this for 2 days. But I now tried it on another network and it works. I've realized that the real question is that I can't even ping the other public IP address (on the other network I've tried). I've tried to set the router to respond to ping in both networks. But it only works in one of the networks. So It must be some sort of ISP problem. Or what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

If your server is behind a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), you have to setup port forwarding in your router. Opening a port is not enough.
What is the local address of the machine with the server? On which port does your server run? Some ports might be blocked by ISP (for example port 25 is often blocked to prevent spam, some ISPs block common [P2P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) ports).

Comment: When i wrote open ports, i meant that i forwarded port 1234 in my router to my local IP 192.168.1.2 (the machine with the server). And in the firewall on the machine(192.168.1.2) I opened port 1234 for TCP connections from all traffic.